# Need explanation on what this mail means titled 'Keep in View'

Tags: interviewing, terminology

I have received this mail titled 'Keep in View' after a job interview. The interview went well. I can not understand what they are trying to tell me.

> Dear xxxx,
>
> Thank you for attending the interview(s) for the role of a yyyyyy.
>
> While the selection committee was impressed with your background and
>   experience, we are keeping your application in view for future
>   opportunities.
>
> Thank you for your interest in our company.

Comment: What is your actual question here? The mail seems clear enough.

Comment: Thank you all for responding. What I can not understand is that If my background and experience impressed them, why are they keeping me in view? Then, is the " Keep in View" promise real or fake?  They are still advertising and conducting interviews for similar positions after my interview. I even applied for one of the latest job advertisements but I was not called for interview.

Answer (score 12):

That simply looks like a - very polite - rejection e-mail.

If you are not convinced, you can try to reach out back asking if there is any specific feedback that they can provide about the interview, or if there is any other position open for which they feel you could be suitable. But other than that, I don't think there's much else you can do.

Comment: since he asked about the specific phrase, the "keep in view" likely means that although they will not hire the OP for the current position, they will retain the OP's resume for potential future opportunities.

Comment: @Link0352, they might be holding onto it, but I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for a call from them.

Answer (score 1):

The vagueness seems benevolently intentional.

This could mean a polite rejection, or that they will review the application in case all preferred candidates reject the actual job offer (or quit or give reasons for termination), or that they might indeed review old applications if a second, identical job is vacant.

Option 3 is likely very rare.

In some localities, there also might be legal necessity for them to notify you when they reserve option 2 or 3 instead of sending back/destroying your application - alternatively, they might perfectly well intend to destroy it but want to avoid both the impoliteness and the hassle of not returning it (which might be considered impolite in some localities).

The vagueness is there so that absolutely no *promise or commitment* to do or not to any of these can be implied and used as a reason to pester them or even seek legal action.